# Why is Docker saying that the requirements.txt file doesn't exist?

Tags: python, docker, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The command is:

`docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.6" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r /var/task/requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/; exit"`

And I am running it from the same folder as the requirements.txt file.

I get the following error: `ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/requirements.txt'`

Comment: Does the file `/var/task/requirements.txt` exist _inside the container_?

Comment: I think $PWD should be without quotes.

Comment: This will not save installed packages into your image

Comment: @JohnGordon how do I check? I am new to Docker and keep trying to run bash, but it keeps saying it's exited.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia that makes no difference.

Comment: @C.Nivs Can you elaborate? I am trying to install the packages from inside of the container as per: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Quite the opposite; depending on the name of the current working directory, you *must* quote it to avoid pathname generation or word-splitting.

Comment: Once the container exits, any extra work you did is lost. So if I were to do `docker run -it python:3.8 "-c /bin/bash pip install requests -t /tmp"` and started a new container, `/tmp` would be empty, because the packages need to be part of the image which is created from a dockerfile

Comment: @C.Nivs I don't see how that applies to *this* command, where `/var/task` is explicitly mounted (we assume correctly and containing `requirements.txt`) before trying to run `pip install -r` to use that file.

Comment: @chepner `/var/task` is mounted, but `site-packages` is not. So the packages will install into the running container in site-packages, then it will exit, and the packages go away

Comment: @chepner nevermind, just read through OPs link

Comment: Short of some sort of permissions issue with Docker that I am not familiar with, the only thing I can think to blame is that `$PWD` doesn't have the value you think it does. Does `ls "$PWD"/requirements.txt` show the file you expect to be used?

Comment: @chepner It does. I'm convinced that the issue is that I'm running it on WSL2 which is not playing nicely with Docker.

Comment: Not sure if it would make a difference, but can you try using `--mount type=volume,src="$PWD",dst=/var/task` instead of `-v "$PWD":/var/task`, or maybe the same with `type=bound` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a "Docker on WSL2" issue, not a Docker issue.